# Minicart qty increment and decrement error -

Tags: ajax, magento2.4.1

I am using the following module for minicart qty increment and decrement,

https://github.com/kirtinariya1/MinicartAjaxQtyIncrementDecrement,

error :

[image]

[image]

Custom Module:

Path : app\code\Zero\MinicartQty\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/decorate',
    'mage/collapsible',
    'mage/cookies',
    'loader'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.sidebar', widget, {

            _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
                var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

                var btnplus = elem.data('btn-plus');
                var btnminus = elem.data('btn-minus');

                this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                    'item_id': itemId,
                    'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val(),
                    'item_btn_plus': btnplus,
                    'item_btn_minus': btnminus,
                }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
                // this._customerData();
            },


       /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
        },

                /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
                 _removeItem: function (elem) {
                    var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
        
                    this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
                        'item_id': itemId
                    }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
                },

        
        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
         _showItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
                itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
            } else if (elem.val() == 0) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            } else {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            }
        },





            /**
             * Update content after update qty
             *
             * @param {HTMLElement} elem
             */
            _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
                var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

                if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                    $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

                    if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                        window.location.reload(false);
                    }
                }
                // this._hideItemButton(elem);
                this._customerData();
            },

            _customerData : function ()  {
                var sections = ['cart'];
                customerData.invalidate(sections);
                customerData.reload(sections, true);
                this._hideItemButton();
            }

        });
        return $.mage.sidebar;
    }
    
});
```

Core file :

vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'underscore',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'mage/decorate',
    'mage/collapsible',
    'mage/cookies',
    'jquery-ui-modules/effect-fade'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.sidebar', {
        options: {
            isRecursive: true,
            minicart: {
                maxItemsVisible: 3
            }
        },
        scrollHeight: 0,
        shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,

        /**
         * Create sidebar.
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {
            this._initContent();
        },

        /**
         * Update sidebar block.
         */
        update: function () {
            $(this.options.targetElement).trigger('contentUpdated');
            this._calcHeight();
        },

        /**
         * @private
         */
        _initContent: function () {
            var self = this,
                events = {};

            this.element.decorate('list', this.options.isRecursive);

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + this.options.button.close] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(self.options.targetElement).dropdownDialog('close');
            };
            events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
                var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                    customer = customerData.get('customer'),
                    element = $(this.options.button.checkout);

                if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                    // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
                    $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);

                    if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
                        element.prop('disabled', true);
                        location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                    } else {
                        authenticationPopup.showModal();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
                element.prop('disabled', true);
                location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
            }, this);

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                confirm({
                    content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                    actions: {
                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        confirm: function () {
                            self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                        },

                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        always: function (e) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
                self._showItemButton($(event.target));
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['change ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
                self._showItemButton($(event.target));
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + this.options.item.button] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                self._updateItemQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['focusout ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
                self._validateQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };

            this._on(this.element, events);
            this._calcHeight();
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _showItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
                itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
            } else if (elem.val() == 0) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            } else {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {*} origin - origin qty. 'data-item-qty' attribute.
         * @param {*} changed - new qty.
         * @returns {Boolean}
         * @private
         */
        _isValidQty: function (origin, changed) {
            return origin != changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                changed.length > 0 &&
                changed - 0 == changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                changed - 0 > 0;
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @private
         */
        _validateQty: function (elem) {
            var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (!this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                elem.val(itemQty);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                'item_id': itemId,
                'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val()
            }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after update qty
         *
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         */
        _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
            var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

            if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

                if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                    window.location.reload(false);
                }
            }
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _removeItem: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
                'item_id': itemId
            }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after item remove
         *
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @private
         */
        _removeItemAfter: function (elem) {
            var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

            if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                $(document).trigger('ajax:removeFromCart', {
                    productIds: [productData['product_id']],
                    productInfo: [
                        {
                            'id': productData['product_id']
                        }
                    ]
                });

                if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.shoppingCartUrl) === 0) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Retrieves product data by Id.
         *
         * @param {Number} productId - product Id
         * @returns {Object|undefined}
         * @private
         */
        _getProductById: function (productId) {
            return _.find(customerData.get('cart')().items, function (item) {
                return productId === Number(item['item_id']);
            });
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} url - ajax url
         * @param {Object} data - post data for ajax call
         * @param {Object} elem - element that initiated the event
         * @param {Function} callback - callback method to execute after AJAX success
         */
        _ajax: function (url, data, elem, callback) {
            $.extend(data, {
                'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                // showLoader:true,

                /** @inheritdoc */
                beforeSend: function () {
                    elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },

                /** @inheritdoc */
                complete: function () {
                    elem.attr('disabled', null);
                }
            })
                .done(function (response) {
                    var msg;

                    if (response.success) {
                        callback.call(this, elem, response);
                    } else {
                        msg = response['error_message'];

                        if (msg) {
                            alert({
                                content: msg
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        },

        /**
         * Calculate height of minicart list
         *
         * @private
         */
        _calcHeight: function () {
            var self = this,
                height = 0,
                counter = this.options.minicart.maxItemsVisible,
                target = $(this.options.minicart.list),
                outerHeight;

            self.scrollHeight = 0;
            target.children().each(function () {

                if ($(this).find('.options').length > 0) {
                    $(this).collapsible();
                }
                outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);

                if (counter-- > 0) {
                    height += outerHeight;
                }
                self.scrollHeight += outerHeight;
            });

            target.parent().height(height);
        }
    });

    return $.mage.sidebar;
});
```

Comment: You modified this sidebar.js of that module?

Comment: Yes, i am modified.

Comment: Without modified this module running perfect. Can you please share your module link?

Comment: What version you are using, i am using 2.4.1 commerce edition.

Comment: I am using same.

Comment: Sure, can  u pls share your module? let me test with my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122987/discussion-between-zus-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Did you face any delay when you click the plus or minus button?

Comment: My module: https://we.tl/t-HSsBBWzomc

Sometimes double-time click only update the qty and 2 to 3 seconds delay there when i click + or - button.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122987/discussion-between-zus-and-rohan-hapani

Comment: @zus, Refer this link, http://gsyfuy.blogspot.com/2019/04/adding-quantity-increment-button-in.html

Answer (score 1):

The `_hideItemButton(elem);` function requires an argument of `elem` which you are not passing in within the `_customerData` function:

```
     /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

        $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
    }

    ...

    _customerData : function ()  {
       ...
       this._hideItemButton();
    }
```

So the possible fix will be to pass `elem` into the `_customerData` function and then also pass it in to the `_hideItemButton` function like so:

```
         /**
         * Update content after update qty
         *
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         */
        _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
            var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

            if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

                if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                    window.location.reload(false);
                }
            }
            // this._hideItemButton(elem);
            this._customerData(elem);
        },

        _customerData : function (elem)  {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        }
```

There are other ways to fix it such as removing the final line in `_customerData` and uncommenting `// this._hideItemButton(elem);` in `_updateItemQtyAfter` which will achieve the same thing.

Comment: My code: If i click + button the button disable until qty updated, after updated with your code if i click + button is ready to click without update the qty button https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YIJkSvCFFvqIKSZpVyMniPAJn_6rTwIG/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Current Code: https://codeshare.io/a3rVo1

Comment: Does the error still occur?

Comment: Yes, still that error happen.

Comment: My current code : https://codeshare.io/5eDByx